# VSCodeでCSSの補完がしたい

Tags: css, vscode

CSSファイルで`.`を入力すると
VSCodeで開いているHTMLファイルから
使用されているClass名が補完されるプラグインはありませんか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

検索してみただけですが、これはどうでしょう。
説明には両方向の補完がサポートされているとあります。
[IntelliSense for CSS, SCSS class names in HTML, Slim and SCSS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gencer.html-slim-scss-css-class-completion)

> Both directions (from CSS/SCSS to HTML, Latte... or from HTML, Latte to CSS/SCSS...) are supported. Only changed parts will be re-indexed so this will give you almost instant auto-completion.
>
> 両方の方向（CSS/SCSSからHTML、Latte... またはHTML、LatteからCSS/SCSS...）がサポートされています。変更された部分のみが再インデックス付けされるため、ほとんど瞬時に自動補完が行われます。

---

なお、説明の先頭にこんな注意がありました。

> Note: This is drop-in replacement for https://github.com/zignd/HTML-CSS-Class-Completion. Please uninstall that extension before installing this. Otherwise, things can happen.
>
> 注：これはhttps://github.com/zignd/HTML-CSS-Class-Completionのドロップイン置換です。 これをインストールする前に、その拡張機能をアンインストールしてください。そうでなければ、問題が起こる可能性があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。一度ファイルを保存しないと補完判定してくれないところに少し手間取りましたがこれで補完できました。